# Field undefined if i create a route without a wrapper function

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I basically have this route:

```ts
// userRoutes.ts

const userRouter = Router();

// create user
userRouter.post('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    createUserFactory().handle(req, res)
});
```

createUserFactory:

```ts
// createUserFactory.ts
export function createUserFactory(): CreateUserController {
    const userRepository = new UserRepository();
    const createUserUseCase = new CreateUserUseCase(userRepository);
    const createUserController = new CreateUserController(createUserUseCase);

    return createUserController;
}
```

Alright, but if i use the route like this:

```ts
userRouter.post('/', createUserFactory().handle);
```

the `createUserUseCase` inside the `createUserController` is null.

but if i use the route like this, it works, any idea why?:

```ts
userRouter.post('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    createUserFactory().handle(req, res)
});
```

Comment: Maybe the `handle` function uses `this`. When you use `someClassInstance.method` as a value and then call that function, it doesn't have the correct `this` value.

Comment: yeah, it use `this`, i think it makes sense now. Thank you